# Is there a way to make pattern encryption of a password secure

Tags: javascript, encryption

I make a userscript that replaces a password field with a 3x3 pattern unlock. How it works is in the [settings](https://github.com/sizzlemctwizzle/GM_config) of the userscript the user enters their password, enters a [pattern](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/patternLock.html), and that value is [encrypted](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) and that value is saved. The password is encrypted with the output of the pattern lock, which is just a string of one-digit numbers of the pattern. Only full 9 point patterns can be used. The unencrypted password is never saved, but by looking at the code, it can't be hard to crack. There are ~360000 combinations of patterns to decrypt the encrypted password. Is there something more I can do?

Comment: 360000 combinations????? Hard to crack????? That takes like a minute

Comment: Inventing your own encryption is rarely a good idea.  Secure encryption is hard to do.

Comment: What you describe sounds essentially like a password manager with a pattern lock instead of the master password. Look into how they store passwords. Also don't let the user enter their own password, but randomly generate a high-entropy one.

Comment: Where do you store the encrypted password? What kind of attack are you trying to guard against? Who would be able to "crack" anything?

Comment: I'm saying that it's easy to crack and I want to know if there's a better way to do what I'm doing. A password manager with a pattern lock is essentially what my script does. It's to log in faster than it takes to type in a password. That's why I need to use the original user's password. I use that to log in once it's been decrypted. The value is stored using GM_Config which uses the browser's storage. The attack I'm trying to prevent is how easy it is to, if you can get the encrypted password, to test all combinations of patterns to decrypt it.

Comment: Assuming the values are stored securely enough by GM_Config, I can save a random salt and use that for encryption and description.